# Does string contain any of the words in my list?

Tags: python, string, list, search

I want to check a string to see if it contains any of the words i have in my list.
the list is has somewhere around 100 individual words.

i have tried using regex but cant get it to work...

```
string = "<div class="header_links"><a href="/Restaurants-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand.html?pid=6">$$ - $$$</a>, Dansk, <a href="/Restaurants-g189541-zfz10697-Copenhagen_Zealand.html">Veganske retter</a>, <a href="/Restaurants-g189541-zfz10992-Copenhagen_Zealand.html">Glutenfri retter</a></div>"

list = ['Café','Afrikansk','............','Sushi','Svensk','Sydamerikansk','Syditaliensk','Szechuan','Taiwansk','Thai','Tibetansk','Østeuropæisk','Dansk']
```

in this case the string has 'Dansk' in it. The string could contain more than one of the words in the list.

i want to write a piece of code that prints the words in the list which is also in the string.

in this case the output should be: Dansk
if there was more than one word in the string it should be: Dansk, ...., ....

I hope someone can help

Comment: Your string variable seems to have been cut into pieces by the multiple `"` in your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with a membership check:

```
[x for x in lst if x in string]
```

Note that I have renamed your list to `lst`, as `list` is built-in.

**Example**:

```
string = '<div class="header_links"><a href="/Restaurants-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand.html?pid=6">$$ - $$$</a>, Dansk, <a href="/Restaurants-g189541-zfz10697-Copenhagen_Zealand.html">Veganske retter</a>, <a href="/Restaurants-g189541-zfz10992-Copenhagen_Zealand.html">Glutenfri retter</a></div>'

lst = ['Café','Afrikansk','Sushi','Svensk','Sydamerikansk','Syditaliensk','Szechuan','Taiwansk','Thai','Tibetansk','Østeuropæisk','Dansk']

print([x for x in lst if x in string])
# ['Dansk']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list = ['Café','Afrikansk','............','Sushi','Svensk','Sydamerikansk','Syditaliensk','Szechuan','Taiwansk','Thai','Tibetansk','Østeuropæisk','Dansk']
>>> string = """<div class="header_links"><a href="/Restaurants-g189541-Copenhagen_Zealand.html?pid=6">$$ - $$$</a>, Dansk, <a href="/Restaurants-g189541-zfz10697-Copenhagen_Zealand.html">Veganske retter</a>, <a href="/Restaurants-g189541-zfz10992-Copenhagen_Zealand.html">Glutenfri retter</a></div>"""
>>> [x for x in list if x in string]
['Dansk']
```

I recommend not using `list` as a variable name, as it usually referring to the `type` `list` (like `str` or `int`)

Comment: `if x in string`.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can use:

```
string_intersection = set(string.replace(',', '').split()).intersection(my_list)

print(*string_intersection, sep =',')
```

output:

```
Dansk
```